# Windows 10 turned grey scale display

Tags: windows-10

My windows environment has become all grey.  I don't know what happened.

Solutions like these didn't work for me:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-pictures/my-computer-screen-spontaneously-turned-grayscale/b11188d3-db39-43fb-859b-f730eb3e8497?auth=1

https://paulrobichaux.com/2017/10/06/my-screen-went-gray-how-to-turn-off-windows-10-color-filter-mode/ --- I can't find the "Color & high contrast" window

The only time I get color is when windows starts up and asks me to login.  But as soon as I login, everything turns grey.

How do I get color back into my windows environment?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out

In windows search, type high-contrast settings.  Then it showed up.  ANd i turned off the filter

Answer (score 1):

Its most probably because you pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> by mistake while doing a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> toggles the color filter (Grey scale by default) under the "High Contrast settings". Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> again to toggle.